# Model.save() suddenly not working after upgrade

Tags: rally

I have some custom Rally apps deployed in Agile Central. After upgrading to version 2017.1, the Rally.data.wsapi.Model.Save() method is no longer working. The app still works without problems in the environment using version 2016.2-1.

Here's one of the functions calling the save(), that has stopped working:

```
_addCost: function(){
        var team = this.down('#cb-team') && this.down('#cb-team').getRecord(),
            cost = this.down('#nb-cost') && this.down('#nb-cost').getValue(),
            asOfDate = this.down('#dt-asOfDate') && this.down('#dt-asOfDate').getValue() || new Date(),
            userName = this.getContext().getUser().UserName;

        this.logger.log('_addCost', team, cost, asOfDate, userName);
        var grid = this.down('rallygrid');
        if (grid){
           var newPref = Ext.create('ProjectCostModel',{
                Project: team.get('_ref'),
                Workspace: this.getContext().getWorkspace()._ref
            });
            newPref.setCostForProject(cost, asOfDate, userName);
            if (this._validate(grid.getStore(), newPref)){
                newPref.save();
                grid.getStore().add(newPref);
            }
        }
},
```

The full source code for the app is here: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/portfolio-cost-apps

Does anyone have any solutions? I'm new to rally apps, so I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Are there any errors in the dev console?  Or errors returned from the network request?

Comment: @KyleMorse I got a response from a put method of "Not authorized to create: Preference"

Comment: That sounds like a permissions issue.  It's very possible that there was an outstanding permissions hole in your previous onprem version that has now been fixed.  Is your user a project admin?  Because I think that's what's required to create a preference at the project scoped level...

Comment: @KyleMorse Thanks for the help! It did indeed turn out to be a permissions issue. I was able to correct it, and now everything is working properly.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it!